# Why am I unable to make/use custom resolutions?

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr

This question has been asked several times, but I haven't seen any helpful answers for it, and many of the posts are quite old now. Apologies if this is out of line. =)

I'm having trouble adding more resolutions on Ubuntu MATE 18.04. I want to add new resolutions to play with games. Every guide I've read showing how to add resolutions to Ubuntu tells you to follow these steps (using 1280x720 60hz as an example):

```
me@example-pc:~$ cvt 1280 720 60
```

Which echoes:

```
# 1280x720 59.86 Hz (CVT 0.92M9) hsync: 44.77 kHz; pclk: 74.50 MHz
Modeline "1280x720_60.00"   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync
```

You then copy everything after "Modeline", and paste it after 'xrandr --newmode':

```
me@example-pc:~$ xrandr --newmode "1280x720_60.00"   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync
```

Sometimes this comes up with an error, but when I rebooted to test this question, it didn't happen.

After that, you copy the previous part in quotations and put it after 'xrandr --addmode (output)'

```
me@example-pc:~$ xrandr --addmode DVI-D-0 "1280x720_60.00"
```

Here, at the final step, I get an error echoed to me. I don't know what it is telling me.

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
   Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
   Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
   Serial number of failed request:  33
   Current serial number in output stream:  34
```

After this step, you're advised to do another step to save it for your next boot, which I haven't tried yet. The resolution I've tried to add doesn't appear in Display Settings, and I can't switch to it in games that list all the resolutions in Ubuntu by default. If I use 'xrandr' to list my resolutions, I get:

```
me@example-pc:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axi
s) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95
   1600x1200     60.00
   1440x900      59.89
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1280x960      60.00
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1280x720_60.00 (0x2cf) 74.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1472 total 1664 skew    0 clock  44.77KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  748           clock  59.86Hz
```

For my situation, a solution to xrandr or an alternative I can use with my pc or with games is much appreciated, but many people have this issue with their actual desktop, so if anyone has a real solution with xrandr, please share!

Comment: I just ran into this problem with 4K tv. I ordered new thunderbolt adapter for 4k @60 Hz but even then the highest I achieved was 3840*2160@54Hz. Trial and error until problem solved was the recipe.

Comment: What would you be suggesting by "trial and error"? =o

Comment: Try 1280x720_45 to see if refresh rate too high was causing error. Also is 1280x720 a normal resolution in the first place and why did you pick this Width x Height?

Comment: trying higher and higher resolutions, so you can find which is the highest you can get

Comment: @Comar OP is lowering resolution. Check the ones already supported by `xrandr` above.

Comment: I tried 45, but the same error appears. I chose 1280x720 because its a fairly common 16:9 resolution =) If I try this with 1920x1080 60, I get the same result and error

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found a way.The final error message implies that you  had already set the resolution earlier.

Despite the fact that you cannot see your desired resolution on the display panel, the OS has it somewhere.

If the resolution was **1600x900**, set it using the following command;

xrandr --size 1600x900

This becomes your new resolution and will be visible from the display panel.